# Why does my express app.get call not work when I add a parameter field?

Tags: http, express, get

I want to route a query using express.js. When I don't specify a parameter, it works fine. That is to say in my browser I input 'localhost:3000/submissions' and up pops my submissions page.

This is the code:

```
app.get('/submissions', function(req, res){
    res.render('submissions');
});
```

However, when I add an input parameter -

```
app.get('/submissions/:title', function(req, res){
    res.render('submissions');
});
```

- it returns 'Cannot GET /submissions'. That's whether or not I append the parameter to the input (i.e. 'localhost:3000/submissions:title=whatever').

Can anyone show me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you define the route as `/submission/:title`, the URL it is mapping is like:

```
http://localhost:3000/submissions/ASampleTitle
```

Not

```
http://localhost:3000/submissions/:title=whatever
or
http://localhost:3000/submissions
```

Please refer to Express' [routing document](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) for the following example:

```
Route path: /users/:userId/books/:bookId
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/users/34/books/8989
req.params: { "userId": "34", "bookId": "8989" }
```

Comment: Nice one. I doubt if I'd have sussed that out any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes the various types of passing data....

```
GET https://localhost:4730/countries  --> No data is passed

appHttps.get('/countries', function(req, res) {
    res.json({"countries":["India,China,USA,Canada,...."]} );
});
```

---

GET https://localhost:4730/states?country=india  --> query param is passed

```
appHttps.get('/states', function(req, res) {
   console.log("Country passed is :"+req.query.country); //Consoles --> india
   res.json({"states":[TamilNadu,Kerala,......]});  
});
```

---

GET https://localhost:4730/capital/TamilNadu --> req param is passed

```
appHttps.get('/capital/:state', function(req, res) {
    console.log("State Passed is "+req.params.state);// consoles --> TamilNadu
    res.json({"state":"Chennai"});
```

}

---

POST https://localhost:4730/postData  --> req body is passed

req body {"name":"nofi"}

```
appHttps.post('/postData', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.name);// Consoles --> nofi
    res.json(req.body);
});
```